# Why doesn't display:inline work for "li a {", only "li {" in CSS?

Tags: html, css, list

I'm learning how to create menus as part of my first website build and came across a tutorial on horizontal vs. vertical. It seems most of it comes down to defining your list as either "block" or "inline" in the CSS. This makes sense to me, but what doesn't is why

```
li a { 
  display:inline; 
}
```

doesn't create a horizontal menu. But doing

```
li {
  display:inline; 
}
```

will create that horizontal menu. I'm guessing it has to do with something about the "li a" vs. just "li" elements. For reference I have all of my list items as a link element. Code:

HTML -

```
<ul>
<li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS for vertical -

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `li` element is by default `display: list-item`. The `a` element is by default `display: inline`. So changing the `a`'s display while not changing its parent does nothing. It's kind of like expecting someone to notice that you've changed your shirt when you've only changed your undershirt. So for a inline list, you need to make the `li`s inline. Making the `a`s block is optional, it just means you can mess around with the padding and/or margin and other properties that you can't change with inline elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/ybkkgpoe/